# Comparing user input to value in struct array

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, compare, user-input

I have project I'm working on for a class in which I have to create a point-of-sale system. I'm trying to run through the range until the user entered option, say 'B' for example, matches menuOption. I've tried 'strcmp' to no avail and I'm fairly new to C++ so my knowledge is still pretty weak. My detective skill haven't yielded any solutions either so any help would be appreciated.

I know the code below is wrong, as it's attempting to compare a 'char' and 'char *', but this is the idea of what I would like to accomplish.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    if ( choice[0] == options[i].menuOption){ 
        subTotal += options[i].price
        itemsOrdered.push_back(options[i].optionName)
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm going about it all wrong.

```
struct Menu {
    char menuOption[1];
    string optionName;
    float price;
};
```

also choice is:

```
char choice[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you decide that choice and menu option are both one char , only use char like this :

```
struct Menu {
    char menuOption;
    string optionName;
    float price;
};

char choice;
```

Then you compare like this :

```
if ( choice == options[i].menuOption)
```

If you want your code to work as it is , just change this line :

```
if ( choice[0] == options[i].menuOption)
```

To :

```
if ( choice[0] == options[i].menuOption[0])
```

Comment: Jesus, I'm an idiot...thank you so much @dev65 I appreciate it.